# Local Facebook Development Environment using WAMP - how to find localhost port number and work on application

Tags: php, facebook, localhost, wampserver

Hi I'm a newbie to web programming and am trying to build an integrated FB application in PHP.  I have already some some sample code stored on the heroku servers but for convenience I am trying to set up a local development environment and have installed WAMP (I'm running Windows 7 32-bit).  I have three questions:

1)  I have been following the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working_locally and am in the process of setting up the developer test app.  It seems that the localhost url is always 127.0.0.1 for every machine, but how can I find out what port number to put?  Or do I simply pick a 4 digit one at random?  In another post someone specified a port for Ruby (or Ruby on Rails, I'm not sure), but I can't find any information on the port for PHP.

2)  The guide mentions that I need to set the APP ID and APP secret as environment variables - how do I do this in WAMP?

3)  Once I have created the test app, how do I actually go about working locally?

Help with any of these questions is much appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to specify a port, the default is 80 for HTTP which PHP uses.

> The guide mentions that I need to set the APP ID and APP secret as environment variables - how do I do this in WAMP?

- Hopefully WAMP is like XAMPP so you should find your vhosts file equivalent and enter the following

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /Users/adam/Sites/mycoolapp-dev
      ServerName mycoolapp-dev.localhost
      SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_ID 964173273189
      SetEnv FACEBOOK_SECRET dcd5d23d003d53cb2b68e01
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Something like `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` should be the location. So you'll need to read up on Virtual Hosts for this to work, if you encounter errors

> Once I have created the test app, how do I actually go about working locally?

- You code and save, and either create a new test app different from the one pushed to Heroku in your app settings or change the URLs in the original app settings to match your localhost URL. If everything is set your app should be able to work locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a protocol analyzer like wireshark, to find on which port the packets are being sent and received.
2. Heroku by default sets the environment variables for you. You can check it by calling `phpinfo()`.

   You can do that manually also by

   ```
      <?php
    putenv("APP_ID=$APP_ID");
      ?>
   ```

Answer (score -3):

```
var_dump($_SERVER); // should give you all the info you need
```

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the questions, which you'd know if you'd read the question at all.

Comment: So you're bashing someone for not reading tutorials, while admitting to not bothering to read the original poster's question prior to answering? Pot, meet kettle.

Comment: Hi CBroe - I said I was following some instructions and if you had clicked the link I provided you would have seen that I am indeed asking for help to understand some tutorial instructions!  I've been reading tutorials all day trying to get this to work but like I said I'm entirely new to this area so have still been having trouble getting it to work.  Thanks by the way ceejayoz!

Comment: Sorry, but question 2 and 3 are IMHO clearly answered in the tutorial you linked.